# I cant put user output to put it in mysql workbench whats wrong in this.Help me guys

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I cant put user output to  put it in mysql workbench whats wrong in this.Help me guys.

```
def amount_ofmoney(self):
    id_ask = int(input("Enter ur acc id:"))
    result =self.checkidname(id_ask)
    while result==False:
      print("Invaild id")
    else:
      amount = int(input("Enter the amount of money u wan to put in ur acc:"))
      if amount > 100000:
        print("Sorry choose less amount") 
      else:
        sql = "insert into bank_table(money_amount)  values(%s)"
        val = (amount)
        self.mycursor.execute(sql,val)
        self.mydb.commit()
```

The error is like this

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a space between 'table' and '(' and also between 'values' and '('.

sql = "insert into bank_table (money_amount) values (%s)"